# Can't see my SQLite3 tables in terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I opened the SQLite3 console in my terminal and type `.tables`, but it returns nothing.

This is a problem because I have my website running in the background and I can login, logout, load news, etc.

I don't know where the tables and everything are stored.

This are some of my configuration:

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

Previously I was working on Cloud9.io and I could display everything in the terminal.

Comment: Yeah, I personally don't like the switch of the recent Rails Tutorial to using Cloud9... anyway, what exactly is your question? How to open up SQLite console?

Comment: Using SQLite, your database is in a file under the `/db` directory. You'll need an SQLite editor to view its contents.

Comment: The first line of you code is indented. On most ruby code that won't have an effect, but as this is a YAML file, it will. Is that how your file actually looks or have you made a mistake when adding the code to the question?

Comment: Your YAML configuration information data appears to have not been pasted in correctly. I fixed the indentation. Confirm whether your original data is incorrectly indented or whether this was just paste error.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it, you launched the `sqlite3` command-line utility directly. The thing is, you didn't open a database file with it, which is why it shows no tables.

Instead you should run `rails dbconsole` or just `rails db`. That will work even for other database systems, like PostgreSQL (using `psql`) and MySQL.

However, you could as well use `rails console` and just fetch your data as you would in Rails.

Comment: Perfect, i searched it on Google but i didn't know how to formulate the question !
Thanks mate !